# Extend capacity of slice wrapped in interface type using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I want to extend the capacity of a slice using reflection, but the variable itself is an `interface{}` and I need to get the underlying type first. However, trying to access the underlying type results in having an unaddressable value that I can't extend the capacity of. I know I need to pass in a pointer to the slice, because otherwise the unaddressable value won't bubble my changes up, but if I pass a pointer to `reflect.ValueOf`, I get a Pointer->Interface->Slice situation, whereas I want Pointer->Slice, i.e. an addressable version of the slice.

I've got a minimal example thrown together to demonstrate the problem. The `extend` function receives a variable of type `any` that is actually a slice (could be a slice of any type, e.g. `[]any`, `[]string`, `[]MyStruct`). In my particular situation I can't use generics, this example is just a boilt down version of the preconditions that led here.

In my example I have the things I have tried listed, also available online: https://go.dev/play/p/LBOrORw3oSs

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func extend(v any) (any, error) {
    // however, on array set, we can test if the value is maybe an array:
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    rt := rv.Type()
    kind := rt.Kind()
    if kind != reflect.Slice {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("value is not a slice, but rather %T", v)
    }
    c := rv.Cap()
    c = c*2 + 1
    // this panics because rv is not addressable
    rv.SetCap(c)
    // in consequence, this panics as well, because rv is not addressable
    rv.Addr().SetCap(c)
    // I tried getting a pointer to the value
    ptr := &v
    rvPtr := reflect.ValueOf(ptr)
    rvPtr.SetCap(c)        // panics because kind is Pointer
    rvPtr.Elem().SetCap(c) // panics because kind is Interface
    // calling elem twice gives me the correct kind (slice) because now I got the underlying type,
    // but now we have the same situation as before: unaddressable value
    rvPtr.Elem().Elem().SetCap(c)

    // have to return here because we extend the capacity of a slice that is not passed as pointer
    return rv.Interface(), nil
}

func main() {
    slice := []any{}
    result, err := extend(slice)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(cap(result.([]any)))
}
```

Comment: I doubt you can do what you want. You can modify the slice only if you got an addressable value, so you have to work on a pointer-to-slice. In your nomenclature interface->pointer->slice. But this sounds like a XY-Problem and you might simply return the cap-increased slice instead of modifying it in place (which is not possible, e.g. append also cannot do it).

Comment: I'm aware I have to return the modified slice, and that is my intention. But I still would like to be able to receive an addressable version of the slice. In a non-reflection based version, I could do it. Just extend the capacity and return that. Why can't I obtain an addressable value of the slice, even though just within the function scope?

Comment: Because the value inside an interface is not addressable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to get an addressable version? In non-reflection style, I could also do this: s, ok := v.([]any). And then extend the capacity of s and return s. I guess I'm getting closer to understanding the core issue. Shouldn't it be possible to obtain an addressable version of the underlying value?

Comment: That s is a different one than the one stored in the slice. This different one is addressable but that doesn't make the non-addressable adressable.

Comment: But that's exactly what I'd like to achieve. Get an addressable value to the slice, extend the capacity, and then return that value. I understand that `s` is different, but in the end, but it does not copy the entire slice, only the slice header. I would like to get an addressable value of the slice, even if only within local scope, change the capacity and then return that changed slice.

Comment: @LeoReentry: you cannot, it's already been copied, it's not even the original `slice` value within the `extend` function. The only way to modify the slice header in-place is if you start with a pointer to the slice.

Comment: if you want to extend the capacity and return the new slice, that is exactly what [`slices.Grow`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Grow) does already

Comment: @JimB I can't use generics here unfortunately (slices.Grow), because I only receive the slice wrapped in an empty interface, so generics don't apply. The function I posted in the question hopefully demonstrates that

Comment: @JimB I understand it's not the original slice header, I don't care. That's why I stated that I return the slice with the modified capacity.

Comment: @LeoReentry:I think your approach here is what is confusing people, because you are trying to modify the value (and even if it were addressable, you can't just `SetCap` without having adequate storage or it will still panic). You need do it with the same steps you would without reflection -- make a larger slice, copy the elements and return the new slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type is not known until runtime and you can't use [`slices.Grow`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Grow), you can perform the same operation using the `reflect` package.

The method for extending the capacity of a slice using `make` and `copy` directly translates to functions available through `reflect`. You allocate a new slice of the correct type, length and capacity, then you copy the new elements into that slice.

```
func extend(v any) any {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    extended := reflect.MakeSlice(rv.Type(), rv.Len(), rv.Cap()*2+1)
    reflect.Copy(extended, rv)
    return extended.Interface()
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is effectively equal to extending the capacity because extending the capacity of a slice in general also reallocates the backing array, right?

Comment: @LeoReentry: "effectively equal" would imply there's some other mechanism you could use. You can't extend the capacity without allocating a new backing array either via `make` or `append`